# How to concat lists integers and strings into one string?

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have the following variables:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = "de"  # <-- not a (usual) list !
c = 5     # <-- not a list !
d = [4, 5, 23, 11, 5]
e = ["dg", "kuku"]
```

Now I want to concat all `a, b, c, d, e` to one list:

```
[1, 2, 3, "de", 5, 4, 5, 23, 11, 5, "dg", "kuku"]
```

I have tried `itertools.chain` but it didn't work. Please advise how can I make the concatenation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chain` works with iterables.  What you mean is: concatenate these lists and raw values.

I see two steps:

```py
def ensure_list(x):
  if isinstance(x, list):
    return x
  return [x]

lists = map(ensure_list, (a, b, c, d, e))

concatenated = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lists))
```

Comment: I like your solution. Could be modified wit a lambda `map(lambda e: e if isinstance(e, list) else [e], (a, b, c, d, e))` to "save" first 5 lines.

Comment: It could.  I would advise against it, because you would have to add a comment to explain what the lambda does.  Maybe the compromise lies in collapsing the function body into a single return statement: `return x is isinstance(x, list) else [x]`.

Answer (score 4):

You could define a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments and iteratively constructs a list out of them depending on their type like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = "de"  # <-- not a (usual) list !
c = 5     # <-- not a list !
d = [4, 5, 23, 11, 5]
e = ["dg", "kuku"]

def concat(*args):
    out = []
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, list):
            out.extend(arg)
        else:
            out.append(arg)
    return out

print(concat(a,b,c,d,e))
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'de', 5, 4, 5, 23, 11, 5, 'dg', 'kuku']
```

---

Alternatively you could map over the list of args, ensure they're all a list, then use `itertools.chain` to combine the map object like this:

```
def concat(*args):
    return list(itertools.chain(*map(lambda x : x if isinstance(x, list) else [x], args)))

print(concat(a,b,c,d,e))
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'de', 5, 4, 5, 23, 11, 5, 'dg', 'kuku']
```

---

And here's a much more opaque way of accomplishing the same thing just for fun in a list comprehension:

```
def concat(*args):
    return [x
            for arg in args
            for x in (arg if isinstance(arg, list) else [arg])]


print(concat(a,b,c,d,e))
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'de', 5, 4, 5, 23, 11, 5, 'dg', 'kuku']
```

---

You could also create a generator with map that yields either the argument or the argument in a list and then sum it all together with a list (you probably shouldn't actually do this, but it's neat).

```
def concat(*args):
    return sum(map(lambda arg : arg if isinstance(arg,list) else [arg], args), [])

print(concat(a,b,c,d,e))
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'de', 5, 4, 5, 23, 11, 5, 'dg', 'kuku']
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to combine `append()` and `extend()` because one of your examples is not a `list` (`b` and `c`) but a single integer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = "de"
c = 5
d = [4, 5, 23, 11, 5]
e = ["dg", "kuku"]

the_input = [a, b, c, d, e]

result = []
for element in the_input:
    if isinstance(element, list):
        result.extend(element)
    else:
        result.append(element)

print(result)
```

I am not aware of any chain like method to improve that example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, isn't there any chain method that "knows" to append all of them to one list?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this, but here's another way of doing it if you like list comprehensions or one-liners:

```py
to_concat = [a, b, c]
concatenated_list = []

concatenated_list += [item for sublist in [[list_or_val] if not isinstance(list_or_val, list) else list_or_val for list_or_val in to_concat] for item in sublist]
```

Output with `a, b, c = "de", [1, 2], ["dg", "kuku"]` :

```py
In [6]: concatenated_list
Out[6]: ['de', 1, 2, 'dg', 'kuku']
```

---

**How does it work?**

This part:

```py
[[list_or_val] if not isinstance(list_or_val, list) else list_or_val for list_or_val in to_concat]
```

of the list comprehension creates a new list by transforming non-list values (like `a` in our case) into lists (so `"de"` becomes `["de"]`). Let's call it `list_of_lists`. We now want to flatten `list_of_lists` to get our end result, and we can do so by the other part of the list comprehension:

```py
[item for sublist in list_of_lists for item in sublist]
```

*(More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/12096138) on the flattening if you're interested)*

As I've said, I wouldn't recommend this solution. It's quite a mess to understand, and it probably has terrible performance, so it's not suited to larger workloads.

Answer (score 0):

Great question - it lead to making something I will be putting in my utilities toolbox:

### Custom generator - chainanything()

I would create the helper function as a generator rather than returning a list. This keeps it more flexible for usage and is usually a tiny bit faster. I usually do this if I have a function that returns a list.

```
def chainanything(*args, preservestrings=True, recursive=False):
    """
    Generator: yields the contents of a Sequence, or the given object if not a Sequence, one at a time
    
    preservestrings = False will lead to strings being yielded as individual characters. Default = True
    recursive = True will recursively flatten sequences. Default = False
    
    Note: preservestrings = False, recursive = False will only flatten strings which are not part of another Sequence.
    e.g.: 'abc' -> 'a','b','c' but ['ab','cd'] -> 'ab','cd'
    """
    args = [*args]
    for arg in args:
        if not isinstance(arg, Sequence):
            yield arg
        else:
            if preservestrings and isinstance(arg, str):
                yield arg
            elif recursive:
                yield from flatten(arg)
            else:
                yield from arg
```

this can then be used in it's standard form to provide your expected result:

```
def test_preservestring():
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72288401/how-to-concat-lists-integers-and-strings-into-one-string/72288721#72288721
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = "de"  # <-- not a (usual) list !
    c = 5     # <-- not a list !
    d = [4, 5, 23, 11, 5]
    e = ["dg", "kuku"]
    assert [x for x in chainanything(a,b,c,d,e)] == [1, 2, 3, "de", 5, 4, 5, 23, 11, 5, "dg", "kuku"]
```

Or with `join` and `map` to answer the question in the title and concatenate them into a string:

```
def test_join():
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = "de"  # <-- not a (usual) list !
    c = 5     # <-- not a list !
    d = [4, 5, 23, 11, 5]
    e = ["dg", "kuku"]
    assert ''.join(map(str,chainanything(a,b,c,d,e))) == "123de54523115dgkuku"
```

The overall function came out a little longer than one line in order to handle strings in a logical way.

The flatten function recursively flattens sequences - it's another little helper generator I created for my toolbox:

```
def flatten(seq):
    """
    Recursively flattens a sequence (including strings!) and returns all elements in order left to right.
    E.g.: [1,2,[3,4,[5],6],7,[8,9]] -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    """
    for item in seq:
        if not isinstance(item, Sequence):
            yield item
        elif len(item) == 1 and item[0] == item: #eg item = 'a'
            yield item[0]
        else:
            yield from flatten(item)
```

You can grab the latest version of the helpers here: https://dev.azure.com/MusicalNinjas/_git/MikesMath